# App closes when pressing home button

Tags: android, forceclose

Whenever I presses the home button on my application then go back again, the app seems to have stopped. I really don't know why since I haven't done anything yet. So that means the only thing that was executed is my oncreate, onresume, onpause and on destroy. I'm not doing anything in onresume, onpause and destroy. No service started yet or anything just loading and initializing data in oncreate. One another thing is, it is not crashing, it just stopped or closes. No errors. I will share to you my onCreate button. Maybe you will see the reason that is causing this to happen.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_landstar_page);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences(pref_data, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        i = new Intent(this, BGService.class);

        shipmentAvailableLayout = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.shipment_available_layout));
        shipmentNotAvailableLayout = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.shipment_notavailable_layout));
        menu = ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu));
        declineBtn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.declinebtn));
        acceptBtn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.acceptbtn));
        callHelpDeskBtn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.callhelpdeskbtn));
        menuBtn = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menubtn));
        refreshBtn = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.refreshbtn));
        logoutBtn = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoutbtn));
        trackingMsgShipment = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tracking_message_shipment));

        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakeLock");

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BGService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.acceptbtn)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    acceptBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.accept_selected);
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    acceptBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.accept_idle);

                    if(isNetworkConnected())
                    {
                        acceptLoad();

                    }
                    else
                        noConnection();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.declinebtn)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    declineBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.decline_selected);
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    declineBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.decline_idle);
                    declineLoad();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.callhelpdeskbtn)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    callHelpDeskBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_refresh_selected);
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    callHelpDeskBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_refresh_idle);
                    if(isNetworkConnected())
                    {
                        displayProgressSpinner();
                    }
                    else
                        noConnection();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menubtn)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    if(menu.isShown())
                    {
                        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.refreshbtn)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(isNetworkConnected())
                        displayProgressSpinner();
                    else
                        noConnection();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoutbtn)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    try{
                        checkerTimer.cancel();
                        gpsTimer.cancel();
                        counterTimer2.cancel();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("isAccept", preferences.getString("isAccepted",""));

                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Message");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Clicking the log out button will stop your GPS and exit the application. Are you sure?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNegativeButton("Logout",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("isDriverLogin", "True");
                                editor.putString("driverPassword", driverPassword);
                                editor.putString("carrierId", carrierId);
                                editor.putString("CCTID", cctid);
                                editor.putString("shipment", entityShipment);
                                editor.putString("isAccepted", "");
                                editor.commit();
                                getApplicationContext().stopService(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                         })
                        .setPositiveButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            }
                          });


                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        loadSaveDetails(intent);
    }
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.DriverLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.LandstarPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.nesv.landstar.BGService"></service>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

One thing, this does not happen on a rooted samsung s3 and normal samsung s4. Tried it on S duos version 4.0 and lower up to gingerbread. And this happened.

Another question. I tried installing it from the eclipse. This didn't happen. This only happen when I try to install the apk file that came from the bin folder on my device.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to have stopped"? Is there anything in logcat? Do you do anything in any of the other activity lifecycle methods (`onResume`, `onPause`, etc.)?

Comment: I'm assigning a boolean flag on my onResume and onPause like this. isBackground = true and vice versa. What I mean is stopped is that It starts again my app. I'm expecting to be on the same activity when I press my home key. But it starts again on my splash page. The page prior to this. And I checked the running applications on application manager. My application has 0 process. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Override onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() (make sure you call super.onXXX() in each of them) and put a log statement in each to see if the system is deciding to destroy your activity, e.g. because system memory is low. If it does then onCreate() will need to be called again when you go back to the Activity.

The 'dev tools' app has a setting called 'Immediately destroy activities' which will always destroy an Activity when you leave an Activity regardless of whether the system needs RAM.

Comment: The funny thing is as soon as I hit the home button and go back immediately, it starts again.

Comment: What are you doing to 'go back immediately'? Pressing the app icon on the homescreen? Or using the task manager?
That's what it's designed to do. Put logging in onDestroy() to see if it's destroying it. When its destroyed your boolean's value will be lost.

Comment: I'm pressing the app icon on the installed application in my device. Not in my task manager. It does not go in the onDestroy()

Comment: OK so it shouldn't do onCreate() again, check that with a log. It should do onStart() then onResume(), where any class members should still be set. Do a log in onStop() and onStart() and output your boolean's value.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
public class StartupActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (needStartApp()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            // this prevents StartupActivity recreation on Configuration changes 
            // (device orientation changes or hardware keyboard open/close).
            // just do nothing on these changes:
            super.onConfigurationChanged(null);
        }

        private boolean needStartApp() {
            final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final List<RunningTaskInfo> tasksInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1024);

            if (!tasksInfo.isEmpty()) {
                final String ourAppPackageName = getPackageName();
                RunningTaskInfo taskInfo;
                final int size = tasksInfo.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    taskInfo = tasksInfo.get(i);
                    if (ourAppPackageName.equals(taskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName())) {
                        // continue application start only if there is the only Activity in the task
                        // (BTW in this case this is the StartupActivity)
                        return taskInfo.numActivities == 1;
                    }
                }
            } 

            return true;
        }

}
```

launch your home activity from this startup activity.
In manifest

```
<activity android:name=".StartupActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: @ljpv14 did you call your main activity in this line of code if (needStartApp()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

Comment: Yes, I'm calling my main activity. The app has a weird behavior. If I install it via the eclipse adt. This doesn't happen. But when I install it using the installer from the bin folder. The way I could make it to work is to restart the phone and the app don't close anymore everytime I hit the home button. Any ideas?